# yii2 - fetch data with activerecord in FETCH_KEY_PAIR array format

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `developer` (
  `id` bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `parent` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`),
  CONSTRAINT `developer_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `developer` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I want get only `id`,`name` in `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` array from this table and use:

```
Developer::find()->select(['id', 'name'])->asArray()->all();
```

But I can not get the data in `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` format
how can i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `ArrayHelper` for generate array with `key` is `id` field and `value` is `name` field. Use like that:

```
ArrayHelper::map(Developer::find()->select(['id', 'name'])->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name')
```

For more http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html#building-maps

Edit:
You  may use `createCommand`, like that:

```
$res = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT id, name FROM developer')->queryAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

But if you want use `ActiveRecord` see in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/Query.php#L204
In this line not set `fetchMode`.

You may take this class `Query`, `ActiveRecord` and change his. And extends your `Develop` model from new class.

Comment: i know it and this is not  solution , maybe yii2 have another option to choose fetch method.

Answer (score 1):

**add code in controller**

```
public function actionViewdata() {
    $model = new Contact();
    $data = $model::find()
            // ->where(['id' > 0])
            //->orderBy('age')
            ->all();
    return $this->render('viewdata', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'contactdata' => $data,
    ));
}
```

**now in view(viewdata.php)**

```
echo'<pre>';
print_r($contactdata);
```